# XML received from response is out of format

Tags: php, xml, response

Hi im currently using PHP on a linux server to receive response from a WebService hosted on a Windows server.

I am using the following PHP to read the response :-

```
while (!feof($socket)) {
  $result .= fgets($socket, 4096);
}

fclose($socket);

if ($debug) echo '<pre>',$result,'</pre>';
```

Apparently when i received the the response it is out of format, with break lines between tags such as the following :-

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4QBaRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABQMBAAUAAAABAAAASgMDAAEAAAABAAAAAFEQAAEAAAABAQAAAFERAAQAAAABAAAAAFESAAQAAAABAAAAAAAAAAA
AAYagAACxj

insetead of like these :-

```
      </ResponseHdr><ResGetCustAreaSnapshot><cmc:GetCustAreaSnapshot xmlns:cmc="http://tnb.com.my/CGIS/D/cmc_customermgnt"><cmc:MAP_IMAGE_ZOOM1000>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
```

apparently even from here i cannot display the tags without using the code block which formats it properly.

would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction on what to look for to fix this problem.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

'ow do you look at your debug output: inside a browser or inside a terminal ? Could it be that you simply have the xml like tags ("<...>") in the reply swallowed by visualizing it as html in a browser ?

If that is not the case then I would check the content of the reply on a lower level. Use 'tcpdump' or 'wireshark' to dump the actual content without having to rely on a higher level output.

Answer (score 0):

Try `var_dump(htmlspecialchars($result))` instead of `echo`.